How to measure the vibration of an object on a video shot at high speed camera?
I have a video fragment which I split into frames (pictures). I use them in pairs (1 frame with 2, 2 with 3, etc.) to find shifts on x and y axes (i.e. how much I need to shift 1 frame to make it like 2). And based on these values I want to calculate the vibration (in hertz) of the object from the video. How can I connect these ideas? And if there is another approach to calculate the vibration of an object with video, what is it? Thanks!
I have no idea how to implement this yet, so far I have found frame-by-frame shifts (applying 2d fft). Now I'm thinking how I can use (or if there is another approach) frame-by-frame shifts to measure the vibration of the object. I will implement everything in python

Requires tracking. FFT is a good approach but can drift (irrelevant for frequency). Depending on displacement, sub pixel accurate methods. Show data?

@ChristophRackwitz sorry, didn’t get what do you mean by “show data”?

data means [mre]. just data. you know. present it. provide it. give us data. you are asking a programming question. data is the least you should provide to fill your problem description with life. so people can experiment on it. ideally you'd have some code that you have an issue with, but if not that, then at least the data. the data is always expected. this forum is for concrete specific situations. all you provided is a bunch of prose. can't debug that, can't even write code to work on that.

Watch this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eUzB0L0mSCI I think this is what you want. also check out this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QtMTvsi-4Hw
